# Getting This issue in middle of the pipeline execution

Tags: azure, jenkins, devops, jnlp, jenkins-cli

Caused: hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: Channel “hudson.remoting.Channel@3f4ae533:JNLP4-connect connection from X.X.X.X/X.X.X.X:44909”: Remote call on JNLP4-connect connection from X.X.X.X/X.X.X.X:44909 failed. The channel is closing down or has closed down

Getting this issue while execution of the pipeline, this pipeline is running on a windows agent connected using JNLP Protocol requesting help…
Jenkins Version : Jenkins 2.356

I have tried Restarting jenkins but this still persists

Comment: I've found a similar issue on github for your problem and someone has answered this : `The source of our problem was that the windows slave took the self-update and then closed and reopened. If any work or pipeline was running during this shutdown, we were getting this error. Make sure the slaves are not disconnected.`  (https://github.com/nodejs/build/issues/1562). Maybe it can help you

Answer (score 0):

it depends on where and how you run this agent

could be

- used non existing container on agent
- error during agent creation (infrastructure issue)
- wrong agent configuration
- different versions of java on agent and jenkins

i'd start from checking logs

also you can check logs in jenkins "manage->system log" https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/viewing-logs/#logs-in-jenkins

there you can add custom loggers (depends on how you run this agent)